# Spring transaction update entity

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I've got one problem. I create Base Reposiotry:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> {
    public T read(Long id , Class<T> classEntity) {
        if(id == null || classEntity == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        T result = entityManager.find(classEntity , id);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Also i have extended repository from BaseRepository

```
public abstract class PrepareRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> extends BaseRepository<T> implements PrepareEntity<T> {
    @Override
    public T read(Long id, Class<T> classEntity) {
        return prepare(super.read(id, classEntity));
    }
```

I create some implementation for PrepareRepository, when change entity after read

```
 @Override
    public User prepare(User entity) {
       entity.setLogin("some");
       return entity;
}
```

I use OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter. And this fragment from applicationContext.xml

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Finally the question. In databse i have one user with login='AdminUser' and Id=1. When i call method read - in database user change login on 'some'. In logs, i saw update request to DataBase. Can i fixed this?

Comment: I don't understand. You retrieve a managed entity from the database, change its login, and you're surprised that a query is performed to update the login in the database? Why are you modifying the login of the entity if you don't want the login to be modified? It's not a bug, it's a feature: managed entities are... managed: their state is persisted by JPA. That's the whole point of using an ORM.

Comment: If i modify entity outside the repository, without annotation Transactional, thats all rights, but i want just prepare entity for user, without changing in database. It is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't fix it. Since there is that opensessioninviewfilter there is a transaction for it in there. So your best bet is cloning your object before change it.